# How to set Proxy Auto-Config for cellular data?

Tags: mobile-data, proxy

On the internet, I found the following instructions for simple proxy, but this does not work for proxy PAC:

1. Go to your Android System Settings & tap on Network & Internet.
2. Tap on Mobile network.
3. Tap on Advanced.
4. Tap on Access Point Names.
5. Tap on the APN you are currently using.
6. Enter the IP address and port of the Proxy server you want to use.
7. Save the changes.

How to set Proxy Auto-Config for cellular data? I know it is possible to do that for Wi-Fi.

Note: solutions which use third party apps or a VPN are not suitable for me.

It can be different for different devices, but I need to know in general how I can do it.

Comment: Android supports PAC only with Wi-Fi, not with Mobile Data.

Comment: Can you provide an article / documentation where this is said?

Comment: There is no general documentation for users that explains the features found in Android. OEMs provide guide and support to their customer. So contact your phone manufacturer to inquire about a specific feature. What I've quoted is from a developer's perspective.